# Recursively converting Windows files to Unix files

Tags: files, unicode, recursive, newlines

I have a PHP application with is located on Linux with multiple directories (and sub-directories) and many PHP, JS, HTML, CSS, etc files.  Many of the files have Windows EOL control characters and I am also concerned that some might not be UTF-8 encoded but maybe ISO-8859-1, Windows-1252, etc.  My desire is to convert all files to UTF-8 with LF only.

Looks like I might have a couple steps.

The dos2unix man provides this solution:

```
find . -name *.txt |xargs dos2unix
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11929475 provides this solution:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7068241 provides this solution:

```
find ./ -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

I recognize the first will only convert txt files which isn't what I want but I can easily change to target all files using `-type f`.  That being said, is one solution "better" than the other?  If so, why?  Is it possible to tell which files will be changed without changing them?  When I finally change them, I don't want the date to change, and intend to use dos2unix's `--keepdate` flag.  Should any other options be used?

Next, I will need to deal with encoding.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/805474/1032531 recommends `enca` (or its sister command `encov`) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/64889/1032531 recommends `iconv`.  It also seems like `file` might be applicable.  Again, which one (or maybe something else all together) should be used?  I installed `enca` and when executing `enca --list languages`, it lists several languages but not english (maybe choose "none"?), and I question is applicability.  `iconv` was already installed, however, it does not have a man page (at least `man iconv` doesn't result in one).  How can this be used to recursively check and convert encoding?

Please confirm/correct my proposed solution or provide a complete solution.

Comment: @K7AAY  I thought it was pretty clear, however, modified added "files" in the sentence "My desire is to convert all `files` to UTF-8 with LF only".  The example in dos2unix's example converts only txt files and not all files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a few questions here rolled into one.

Firstly when using find I would always use `--exec` instead of `xargs`.  As a general rule it's better to do things in as few commands as possible.  But also the first two methods write all the file names out to a text stream ready for xargs to re-interpret back into file names.  Its a needless step which only adds (*addmittedly small*) opportunity to fail.

`dos2unix` will accept multiple file names so I would use:

```
find . -type f -exec dos2unix --keepdate {} +
```

This will stack up long lists of files and then kick off `dos2unix` on a whole bunch of them at once.

---

To Find out which files will be touch just drop the exec clauses:

```
find . -type f
```

---

Encoding changes are far more problematic.  Please be aware that there is no way to reliably determine the current encoding of any text file.  It can sometimes be guessed but that is never 100% reliable.  So you can only batch process encoding if you are sure all the files are currently the same encoding.

I would recommend using `iconv`.  It really is the default too for this job.  You can find a man page for it here:

https://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv

There's a working example of how to use `iconv` with `find` here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544669/batch-convert-latin-1-files-to-utf-8-using-iconv